# How to use selenium 2 PageFactory init Elements with Wait.until()?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The code snippet below works fine, but I'm having a little trouble with the `wait.until()` line:

```
wait.until(new ElementPresent(By.xpath("//a[@title='Go to Google Home']")));
```

It works but I want to send my `PageFactory` `WebElement` `homePageLink` instead:

```
wait.until(new ElementPresent(homePageLink));
```

Is there any way to do that?

These new fangled Selenium 2 features have got my head in a bit of a spin and I can't find much documentation.

Thanks.

```
public class GoogleResultsPage extends TestBase {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title='Go to Google Home']")
    @CacheLookup
    private WebElement homePageLink;

    public GoogleResultsPage() {  
        wait.until(new ElementPresent(By.xpath("//a[@title='Go to Google Home']")));
        assertThat(driver.getTitle(), containsString("Google Search"));
    }  
}

public class ElementPresent implements ExpectedCondition<WebElement> {

    private final By locator;

    public ElementPresent(By locator) {
        this.locator = locator;
    }

    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(locator);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use SlowLoadableComponent instead.  It lets me put a delay in between isLoaded()  and load()  so the page keeps retrying until the page is loaded.

Answer (score 21):

I use [PageFactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) with [AjaxElementLocatorFactory](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/59b77199ceca4f56/f29355bbdaba6db9?lnk=gst&q=AjaxElementLocatorFactory) - PageFactory is a support class for the Selenium 2 Page Objects pattern which you are using, and the AjaxElementLocatorFactory is the factory for the element locators. In your case the constructor will looks like:

```
public GoogleResultsPage() { 
    PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 15), this);
}
```

This code will wait maximum of 15 seconds until the elements specified by annotations will appear on the page, in your case the homePageLink which will be located by xpath. You will not need to use ElementPresent class.

Comment: This works but so would SlowLoadableComponent.  So, the question is, which method works better and for which situations?

Comment: Even though it's been a while can you clarify something for me? The Selenium API must have changed a bit, but now the AjaxElementLocatorFactory has 3 parameters instead of 2. Could you give a hand on what the 2nd parameter should be?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in C#? I can't find AjaxElementLocatorFactory.

Answer (score 2):

There was a request for implementation on C#.

Here it is:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
RetryingElementLocator retry = new RetryingElementLocator(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IPageObjectMemberDecorator decor = new DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator();
PageFactory.InitElements(retry.SearchContext, this, decor);
```

Answer (score 1):

AjaxElementLocatorFactory uses SlowLoadableComponent internally. Check the source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/AjaxElementLocator.java)