# AjaxElementLocatorFactory in Webdriver C# Page object model

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is there an equivalent to AjaxElementLocatorFactory in C# webdriver ,I kept searching and i keep coming up java related example and documentation . Can some tell where can i find documentation or some one give me small example , Thank u in advance

Comment: Check out Denis Koreyba's answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36863865/3958437

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it appears that the `AjaxElementLocatorFactory` is implemented as [`RetryingElementLocatorFactory`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects/RetryingElementLocatorFactory.cs) in the .NET version of the API.  Unfortunately, the implementation hasn't been included in any of the Nuget Selenium packages yet.  If you need it right away, maybe consider integrating the classes into your project directly.